# Add field(caption/description) to wordpress - Redux plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i would like to add a caption/description field to this plugin. Can anyone suggest how could i do it?

The Code Start Here...

```
$sections[] = array(
    'title' => __('Home Settings', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'header' => __('Welcome to the Simple Options Framework Demo', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc' => __('Redux Framework was created with the developer in mind. It allows for any theme developer to have an advanced theme panel with most of the features a developer would need. For more information check out the Github repo at: 
<a href="https://github.com/ReduxFramework/Redux Framework">https://github.com/ReduxFramework/Redux-Framework</a>', 'redux-framework-demo'),

'icon_class' => 'icon-large',

'icon' => 'home',


'fields' => array(

    array(
        'id'=>'media',
        'type' => 'media', 
        'url'=> true,
        'title' => __('Media w/ URL', 'redux-framework-demo'),          
        'compiler' => 'true',
        'desc'=> __('Basic media uploader with disabled URL input field.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
        'subtitle' => __('Upload any media using the WordPress native uploader', 'redux-framework-demo'),
        ),                                              
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be too bad. Just a text field or what? I'm one of the core developers behind Redux. You could hop over to our issue tracker for feature requests found here: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/issues

We're very interested in your needs, so let us know. We'll be glad to help.

Comment: I'll second Dovy's comment. Redux is all about community... if a change is needed, let us know! We'll do our best to accommodate!

Comment: A text field would do. I just need to have a caption/description area/text field for the uploaded image in the Home Settings therefore I can manage the text field also. :) Thank you guys. much appreciated.